# Right way to display escape characters as tooltip in swing java application

Tags: java, swing, tooltip, special-characters

I am using setToolTipText method to set the tooltip text in my java application

```
jTextField1.setToolTipText("<html>" + "Line One" +"<br>" + "Line 2" + "</html>");
```

This works fine unless a escape character comes in. Lets say if '\b' it present in the text, a small box is displayed in the tooltip.

What would be the right way to display this '\b' as is in the tooltip ?

Comment: How do you expect the tooltip to display `\b` (which by the way *is* an ASCII character) ? It's a non-printing control character

Comment: *unless a escape character comes in* - remove the escape character when it "comes in", whatever that means.